# Laravel free IDE

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ide

Is there any free Laravel 4 IDE provide autocomplete

I downloaded netbeans but can't get it to support Laravel:

https://netbeans.org/downloads/

thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the answer for netbeans and eclipse

1. Download the following pre-made file that lists the Laravel namespaces: https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822.
2. Create a folder anywhere on your computer to hold this file. For example: C:/laravel_helper/eclipse_laravel_helper.php
3. After you created an Eclipse or NetBeans Laravel project, open project properties and adjust PHP include path to include above created folder.

source: http://raroweb.net/projects/webdev_helper/netbeans/laravel-4-in-eclipse-or-netbeans/

Answer (score 1):

The most sufficient solution I could find is generating helper file for my IDE. Check out this package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
It is more or less IDE agnostic and quite popular.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with netbeans but you can try sublime text from 
 http://www.sublimetext.com/